# Find a function's minimizing set of parameters

Tags: algorithms

I have a function defined by three parameters (or variables): $f(a,b,c)$ This function is not explicitly defined but is actually a piece of code which returns the result of fitting a curve $g(a,b,c)$ to a set of $(x,y)$ points in a 2D space:

O = {$(x_1,y_1,w_1), (x_2,y_2,w_2), ...$}

where $w$ are *weights* associated with each point. The smaller $f$, the better the fit of $g$ with those points. Each one of these points has a weight associated to it.

Each of these three parameters can only assume values from a given discrete set:

A = {$a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., N_a$}

B = {$b_1, b_2, b_3, ..., N_b$}

C = {$c_1, c_2, c_3, ..., N_c$}

Every set $(a_i,b_j,c_k)$ implies a value for $f(a_i,b_j,c_k)$ and as I said, I need to find the $(a_i,b_j,c_k)$ set that returns the **minimum** value for $f$.

What I do to evaluate $f$ is:

1. Take a set of $(a_i,b_j,c_k)$ values and construct a $g_{ijk} (a_i,b_j,c_k)$ curve in 2D space.
2. For each $(x,y)$ point in $O$, find the point in $g_{ijk}$ that is closest to it (euclidean distance)
3. Multiply that distance by the weight ($0<w<1$) associated to that $(x,y)$ point. This gives me a *weighted distance* for each point.
4. After processing all points in the $O$ set, sum all weighted distances.
5. The sum obtained above is what I call $f(a_i,b_j,c_k)$, ie: a measure of how good $g_{ijk} (a_i,b_j,c_k)$ fitted $O$.

So far I've managed to do this through a *brute force* approach where I test every possible combination of $a,b,c$ (ie: $N_a*N_b*N_c$ combinations) one after another and at the end I simply isolate the minimum.

Is there a better/more efficient algorithm to perform this *minimization*, given the restrictions on my function and parameters?

---

### Add

After a bit of research it looks like this falls into the category of *combinatorial optimization problems* for which methods such as [Cross-Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method) seem to be the standard approach.

Comment: It *is* a function in the strict sense, but if you do not assume any other properties, there is nothing more that can be said about finding its minimum value: brute force is all there is. Because you posted this here on a stats forum instead of a math forum, one would guess you have some additional statistical knowledge about the behavior of $f$.  What is it?

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide much more information on $f$. It's basically a fitting function that returns a value according to how well a curve (characterized by a set of $(x,y,z)$ parameters) fits a cloud of points in a 2D space. The goodness of fit is defined through a measurement of how distant (euclidian distance) those points are from the curve.

Comment: That's a *lot* of information that's not contained in your question, Gabriel. What you seem to be telling us is that you have point cloud data, you are approximating those (somehow) with $f$, and you wish to estimate a minimum of $f$. The more you can tell us about (a) the data in that point cloud, (b) exactly how you are constructing $f$, and (c) the costs of imprecision in your estimates of its minimum, then the more helpful and focused the answers can be.

Comment: I'm sorry @whuber, I always try to make my questions as simple and general as possible and sometimes I end up leaving important information out. I've refactored the question, is it better now?

Comment: Often more than half the task of answering a statistical question is figuring out how to ask it in the first place :-). Actually, this phenomenon is [not confined to statistics](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question#comment3286_3351).

Comment: might be better suited for scicomp.SE

Comment: @Memming I hadn't heard about that site before, thanks! It does look like that could be a better site to post this question to. Should I post it there or wait for an admin to move it?

Comment: @Gabriel You probably mean $(a_i, b_j, c_k)$ instead of $(a_i, b_i, c_i)$ in your question. Second, this is a problem of _discrete optimization_, and if you take any book in this direction you may get somewhere.

Comment: @Nico thank you for catching that, already corrected it. I'll look discrete optimization up, thanks again.